# Pagination on php foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery

My code below basically gets a bunch of films from the db and sets the year as the array key then echoes out each film per year. Thats all cool although my results are getting to long and need paginating. I cant find any examples that help my situation as most pagination in php is for while loops - appreciate any help or feedback.

I dont mind if its jquery or php or a combo of both.

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/timeline.php');
mysql_select_db($database_timeline, $timeline);
// select all the events from the database ordered by date:
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM film2 ORDER BY `year` ASC"); 
$filmArray = null;
while($row_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $year = $row_res['year'];
            $filmArray[$year][] = $row_res;
}
//for each year in the film array echo out each film within that year
foreach($filmArray as $year => $films) {
            echo $year;
            echo '<br />';
            foreach($films as $film) {
                            echo $film['event'];
                            echo '<br />';
                            echo $film['name'];
                            echo '<br />';
                         }
}

?>
```

Comment: Take care: when you introduce pagination and keep the above logic of grouping films by years then the pagination either does not produce pages of same length or spreads film from one single year over several pages.

Comment: I suggest to use only a single loop: echo the contents during the first while loop. The injections of a year header can be done with a simple conditional that evaluates if the year of the current and the last film processed has changed. This prevents having to copy the whole array and makes the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have GET parameter, for example, page.
URL: localhost/film.php?page=1

And then

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
    $page = $_GET['page'];
else
    $page = 1;

$entriesPerPage = 20;
$limitFrom = $page - 1;
$limitTill = $limitFrom + $entriesPerPage;
```

And then Your SQL query:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM film2 ORDER BY `year` ASC LIMIT $limitFrom, $limitTill");
```

And in the end, create html links.

```
<a href="film.php?page=<?=$page-1?>">Previous</a>
<a href="film.php?page=<?=$page+1?>">Next</a>
```

Comment: Appreciate this - just needed to see it broken down. Been looking at over complicated pagination tuts which didnt help.